# Managers report

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, vba

I need help in creating a SQL query for my report.
I need to extract data which will show: how many managers in my company have employees example:
2 Managers have 4 directs each.
Like this:

```
Managers                         Employees
1 (number of managers not ID)       2
2                                   4
5                                   10
8                                   12
```

Table structure in Access data base:

Emplid, Last Name, First Name, Supervisorid, HRStatus

Emplid column includes to Supervisorsid because they are to employees.

I have tried to create such report in Excel but failed :(

I juped to VBA but stocked on SQL query.

Here the code:

```
Private Sub SWE_RAPORT()
Dim db As ADODB.connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim SQL As String, dbPath As String, conStr As String

'CHECK WHERE IS THE DB?

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
.AllowMultiSelect = False
.Title = "WHERE IS THE DB?"
.Show
dbPath = .SelectedItems(.SelectedItems.Count)
End With

'CONNECT TO DB

Set db = New ADODB.connection

With db
.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
.connectionString = "Data Source=" & dbPath
.Mode = adModeRead
.Open
End With

'SQL QUERY

SQL = "SELECT A.SupervisorID, COUNT(A.Emplid) AS DIRECTS, A.HRStatus FROM (SELECT Emplid, SupervisorID, HRStatus FROM swe GROUP BY Emplid, SupervisorID, HRStatus) AS A WHERE A.HRStatus <> 'Terminated' and A.HRStatus <> 'Deceased' GROUP BY A.SupervisorID, A.HRStatus;"

'CONNECT TO RS

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

rs.Open SQL, db, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic

'LOAD DATA IN TO THE ACTIVE SHEET

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Dane")
.Cells.Clear
.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs
End With

'CLOSE DB AND RECORDSET

On Error Resume Next
Set rs = Nothing
rs.Close
Set db = Nothing
db.Close
End Sub
```

Thank you for your help,
MIREK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
select count(b.SupervisorID) Managers,
       b.directs Employees
  from (SELECT A.SupervisorID,
               COUNT(A.Emplid) AS DIRECTS
         FROM swe A
         WHERE A.HRStatus <> 'Terminated' 
           AND A.HRStatus <> 'Deceased' 
         GROUP BY A.SupervisorID) b
 group by b.directs;
```

Comment: SQL = "SELECT Count(SupervisorID) as managerowie, number FROM (SELECT SupervisorID, count(*) as number FROM swe WHERE HRStatus <> 'Terminated' AND HRStatus <> 'Deceased' GROUP BY SupervisorID) AS A  group by number"

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your query:

```
SELECT A.SupervisorID,
       COUNT(A.Emplid) AS DIRECTS,
       A.HRStatus
FROM swe as A
WHERE A.HRStatus <> 'Terminated' 
AND   A.HRStatus <> 'Deceased' 
GROUP BY A.SupervisorID,
         A.Emplid,
         A.HRStatus
```

Comment: Hi, I have checked. I'm getting only information that a employee belongs to manager but not the view that example 2 managers (each of them) have 4 directs.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use self join here. Since each employee's supervisor is himself an employee. So you'll have to count number of employees whose supervisor's ID matches with any employee's EmplID.

```
SELECT Sup.EmplID, COUNT(Emp.SupervisorID) AS DIRECTS, Sup.HRStatus
FROM swe AS Sup LEFT JOIN swe AS Emp ON (Sup.Emplid = Emp.SupervisorID)
WHERE Sup.HRStatus <> 'Terminated' and Sup.HRStatus <> 'Deceased'
GROUP BY Sup.Emplid, Sup.HRStatus
```

Hope it helps. Will be glad to answer questions.